# Finding the fully qualified URL of a function annotated with @RequestMapping

Tags: java, url, http-post, spring-web

I have been given a Java project to work with, which contains a function to which I need to make a POST request, from an Angular frontend.

The function is annotated with: `@RequestMapping(value = "/fn", ...)` and will be tested on a local server (Wildfly 8.x).

Where can I find the values that are need to determine the URL that I need to specify in the `HTTP.post()` method (from `HttpClientModule`), from the frontend, to access this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "value" parameter to the @RequestMapping annotation is the relative path in url that will result in invoking the annotated method. BTW, "value" is an alias for "path", so you may see "value=", "path=", or just the raw string without a property name - all three are equivalent.

Note that the Controller object (the object that contains the method) can also have a @RequestMapping, and in that case, the method's path is appended to the controller's path.

So the path would be the application's base url, e.g. `"http://myapp:8080"` plus the controller path, e.g. `"/widgets"`, plus the method path, e.g. `"/list"`, resulting in a url of, e.g. `"http://myapp:8080/widgets/list"`.